# Java: convert List<List<String>> into List<List<Double>>

Tags: java, collections

I have a List-List from a Filereader (String), how can I convert it into a List-List (Double): I have to return a List of the first Values of the line-Array. Thanks.

```
 private List<List<String>> stoxxFileReader(String file, int column) throws IOException {

        List<List<String>> allLines = new ArrayList<>();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {

          br.readLine();
          String line = null;

          while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                  String[] values = line.split(",");  

            allLines.add(Arrays.asList(values));     

        }   
    }
        return allLines;
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use below method to convert all the list of String to Double

```
public static <T, U> List<U> convertStringListTodoubleList(List<T> listOfString, Function<T, U> function) 
   { 
       return listOfString.stream() 
           .map(function) 
           .collect(Collectors.toList()); 
   }
```

Calling Method

```
List<Double> listOfDouble = convertStringListTodoubleList(listOfString,Double::parseDouble);
```

Answer (score 0):

The java.util.stream.Collectors have a handy method for this. Please refer to the below code snippet. You can replace with your logic

```
    Map<String, Integer> map = list.stream().collect(
            Collectors.toMap(kv -> kv.getKey(), kv -> kv.getValue()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to get as output exactly, but it's not that complicated in any case. Assuming you have something like this:

```
[["1", "2"],
 ["3", "4"]]
```

If you want to get all the first elements as Double `[1, 3]` (Assuming the first element is always present):

```
        List<Double> firstAsDouble = allLines.stream()
            .map(line -> line.get(0))
            .map(Double::parseDouble)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If instead you just want to convert all String values to Double and keep the structure the same:

```
        List<List<Double>> matrix = allLines.stream()
            .map(line -> line.stream().map(Double::parseDouble).collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or if you'd like to output a single array with all values (`[1, 2, 3, 4]`), you can flatMap it:

```
        List<Double> flatArray = allLines.stream()
            .flatMap(line -> line.stream().map(Double::parseDouble))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers! Why do I read sometimes List<double> here in the forum? I thought type variables must always be objects, double is a primitive type??

Comment: `List<double>` I don't believe is ever valid, could you point to an example?

I should note that there exists a `double` and a `Double` in Java for this, same as `int` and `Integer`.